# Wix: Environment doesn't get removed from environment variable if INSTALLFOLDER is changed from default

Tags: wix

we have an installer that adds INSTALLFOLDER to the PSModulePath environment variable. We do this with Permanent="no" so it gets removed during uninstall. However, if the user chooses to install not into the default directory of the installer (which is "c:\Program Files (x86)\ourcompany\ourproduct"), removal of the path from the environment variable doesn't happen. What are we doing wrong?

This is the component's code:

```
<Component Id="cmpAddPathToEnvVarPsModulePath" Guid="{someguid}">
                <Environment Id="PSModulePath" Name="PSModulePath" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" Permanent="no" Part="last" Action="set" System="yes" />
                <RegistryKey Root='HKCU' Key='SOFTWARE\ourcompany' >
                    <RegistryKey Key='ourproduct' >
                        <RegistryValue Name='PSModulePathCreated'  Type='integer' Value='1'  KeyPath='yes'></RegistryValue>
                    </RegistryKey>
                </RegistryKey>
            </Component>
```

Any help appreciated,

--
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

During a default installation and uninstallation the INSTALLFOLDER value is the same. During a custom installation the INSTALLFOLDER value is changed, but  during the uninstall INSTALLFOLDER reverts back to the default path. In order to clear the INSTALLFOLDER value from the PSModulePath environment variable you'll have to write the INSTALLFOLDER value into the registry and then read it in during uninstalls so that uninstalls know how to remove that custom path from PSModulePath.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. How would I go about changing the INSTALLFOLDER property during uninstall? Schedule a CA right at the start of the uninstall sequence to read the stored value from the registry and change it from there using MsiSetProperty? Would that work? Is there an easier way? Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: Yes, that would work. Or, you could do it entirely in wix following wix's "Remember Property" pattern - https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/

Comment: I tried with the remember property pattern and scheduled a CA of type 'immediate' after AppSearch that sets the value of 'INSTALLFOLDER' to the remembered value of the 'INSTALLFOLDER' property used during install. I conditioned it to <![CDATA[REMOVE~="ALL"]]>. However, this works only if I uninstall using msiexec -x. If I use msiexe -i and select "uninstall" from the GUI, this doesn't work. To make this work I must condition for <![CDATA[REMOVE~="ALL" OR REMOVE~="DefaultFeature"]]> because in the latter case REMOVE is assigned the value of my one and only feature named "DefaultFeature".

Comment: Shouldn't <![CDATA[REMOVE~="ALL"]]> be the canonical condition for execution during uninstall only? I wonder what's wrong here with my installer.

Comment: Your findings are correct. Uninstalling from ARP vs uninstalling with UI results in two different REMOVE values ("ALL" vs "Feature1,Feature2,..."). So, either condition on REMOVE~="ALL" OR REMOVE~="DefaultFeature" -or- if there is a feature if your MSI that 'must' always be installed you could condition on &CoreFeature=2 so that only when that core feature is removed does your custom action execute.